# Get all the text node that a user selected in an area

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is it possible to get all the text node that a user selected in an area?

I've try selection object(`window.getSelection()`) to get `anchorNode` and `focusNode` for the start text node and the end.

Now I'm trying to get all the text node between the start text node the the end. This issue also need to concern about the child and parent nodes between the two nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `document.selection` class (IE) or the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties (Firefox / Chrome)

```
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

$('get').onclick = function() {
  var text = $('text'),
      selection = '';

  if (typeof document.selection !== 'undefined')
  {
    text.focus();
    var sel = document.selection.createRange();
    selection = sel.text;
  }
  else
  {
    var d = text.selectionStart,
        e = text.selectionEnd;
    for (var i = d; i < e; i++)
    {
      selection += text.value[i];
    }
  }
  alert ("Selected content:\n" + selection);
};
```

**[Working demo](http://jsbin.com/aFuGebu/1/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: hm... My problem is that I'm trying to get all the text node by using [selection object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection). Cause I've to deal with all nodes in a webpage, not just only in a specific text area.